# Convert Double to java.sql.Time

Tags: java, parsing, time, double, datetime-conversion

I am reading data from a cell in Excel file. I have the value of time(milliseconds) in Double i.e. 0.36712962962962964.

I need to convert this value to java.sql.Time format. I tried parsing it using various approaches but it fails. Following is the code.

`timeInDouble = 0.36712962962962964;
 Time time = new Time(Long.parseLong(timeInDouble.toString()));`

The output for this code is:

`java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0.36712962962962964"`

What is the correct way for this conversion?

Comment: Long can only contain natural numbers, so how should it treat 0.36? Becoming 0?

Comment: Yes, so should i multiply the long with 1000 and then pass it to Time() class?

Comment: FYI, the `java.sql.Time` class was years ago replaced by `java.time.LocalTime`, with the adoption of [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The double value represents a part of day duration, where 0 is begin and 1 is the end of the day. Contructor of Time class expects the time in milliseconds. In a day there are 24 x 60 x 60 x 1000 milliseconds. First we convert daouble into the number of milliseconds since the beginning of the day. Then create a time using milliseconds.

```
double timeInDouble = 0.36712962962962964;

// The number of milliseconds since the beginning of the day
long milliseconds = (long) (timeInDouble * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

Time time = new Time(milliseconds);
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Modern solution use *java.time* class [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html).

Convert your string input to `double`, as a fraction of a day, multiply by the number of nanoseconds (or milliseconds perhaps) in a day, adding to the 00:00:00 time-of-day.

```
LocalTime
.MIN
.plusNanos (
    (long)
    (
            TimeUnit.HOURS.toNanos ( 24 )
            *
            Double.parseDouble ( "0.36712962962962964" )
    )
)
```

> 08:48:40

## *java.time*

The [`java.sql.Time`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Time.html) class is a *terrible* hack, pretending to be a time-of-day but actually implemented as a moment by subclassing `java.util.Date`. **Never use this class.**

With the adoption of JSR 310, this class became legacy, supplanted by the [`java.time.LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html) class. A `LocalTime` truly represents a time-of-day without a date and without the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC.

I assume you are correct in saying that this decimal number provided by Microsoft Excel represents a fraction of a 24-hour day. By the way, this is a poor way to represent a time-of-day; a better way is to use text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

Start by parsing your input into a `double` primitive. Normally, I would suggest `BigDecimal` class for accuracy, but I am guessing that Excel uses [floating-point technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) to handle this number, so we will do the same.

```
// Parse your input string as a `double`.
String input = "0.36712962962962964";
double fractionOf24Hours = Double.parseDouble ( input );
```

That input presumably represents a fraction of a 24-hour day. So let's calculate the number of nanoseconds in a day. I suppose Excel uses milliseconds rather than nanoseconds, but the end result may be the same.

```
// Calculate the number of nanoseconds in a day.
long nanosIn24Hours = TimeUnit.HOURS.toNanos ( 24 );
```

We have the constant `LocalTime.MIN` to represent the time-of-day 00:00:00. Add to that the number of nanos representing our desired fraction of a day.

```
// Start at time-of-day zero, adding the amount of time in nanos.
long nanosToAdd = ( long ) ( nanosIn24Hours * fractionOf24Hours );
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.MIN.plusNanos ( nanosToAdd );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/hJvga4).

> localTime.toString(): 08:48:40

### Convert

If you must have `java.sql.Time` object to interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, you can convert back-and-forth. Look to new methods added to the old classes.

```
java.sql.Time t = Time.valueOf( localTime ) ;
```